# v8 -- automatically detect current Isolate

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

say I have a helper function for creating a string (in v8):

```
using namespace v8;

Local<Value> S(const char* inp, Isolate* is) {
    return String::NewFromUtf8(
        is,
        inp,
        NewStringType::kNormal
    ).ToLocalChecked();
}
```

Then I call it from within my function:

```
void Hello(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& arguments) {
    /*doSomeFunction()*/S("hello",arguments.GetIsolate());
    ...
}
```

Is there **any** way that a helper function can be made where the isolate variable (even if it's stored) doesn't have to be passed in every time? Like, is there a way to somehow detect what the current Isolate is when the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

There is `v8::Isolate::GetCurrent()`. Note that it is relatively slow; if you know which Isolate you're in, it might make more sense to store it in a global variable (or class field, or whatever your code structure makes convenient) on your end.